# checking if the user clicked on href after a JQuery modify

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to check if a user clicked on a kind of a href in a specific class.

I am appending the class in jquery because I need to put a different link every time

```
$("#list-dir").append("<a href='' class='add-href'><il class='dir-items'> " + dir_items[i] + " <br> </il></a>")
$(".add-href").eq(i).attr("href", href_element);
```

and it works as it should I can see the class and the correct link in the HTML file. But when I try to check if the user clicks it nothing works for some reason like the class isn't there
[image]

This ^ was how the webpage looks after I modified it with JQuery.

I already tried putting this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".add-href").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("d")

  });
});
```

as most of the answers suggest but it didn't work.

Comment: You've shown us how you generated the link html. But how did you try to "check if the user clicks it", and why didn't it work?

Comment: if the user clicked on the class `add-href` `$(".add-href").on("click", function(e){` and when I try to log something inside to make sure it do something nothing happens. @JonasHøgh

Comment: You bound the click handler only to the elements that existed in the document _at that time_. Go read up on _event delegation_, that is the most commonly used solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I didn't see a single question with this answer (before I knew what event delegation is) why am I getting so many downvotes? Is it because people don't read the whole question?

Comment: @CBroe I suggest that you will post an answer so the question could be nicely soulved

Comment: why dont you create another element like data-href="" and enter the link value? with current layout the user would click on href and the jquery response wont return as the browser will divert visitor to that link.

Comment: @AslanKayardi I posted an answer it worked great. Upvote will be appreciated because this is an important question. I think that people didn't read all of it and they just saw the start of the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBore for giving me the answer. I had to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). after I did it worked perfectly fine. in addition like  Aslan Kayardi said I could of also create another element like  the `data-href` and enter the link in the  value